# Replace strings using List Comprehensions

Tags: python, string, list, list-comprehension

Is it possible to do this example using List Comprehensions:

```
a = ['test', 'smth']
b = ['test Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
     'consectetur adipiscing elit',
     'test Nulla lectus ligula',
     'imperdiet at porttitor quis',
     'smth commodo eget tortor', 
     'Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes']


for s in a:
    b = [el.replace(s,'') for el in b]
```

What I want is to delete specific words from list of sentences. I can do it using loop, but I suppose it is possible using some one-line solution.

I tried something like:

```
b = [[el.replace(s,'') for el in b] for s in a ]
```

but it goes wrong

---

I got a lot of quality answers, but now I have on more complication: what if I want to use combination of words?

```
a = ['test', 'smth commodo']
```

---

Thank you for a lot of answers!
I made speed test for all the solutions and here is the result:
I did it mean of 100 calculations (except the last one, it's too long to wait).

```
                      b=10 a=2   |  b=9000 a=2 | b=9000 a=100 | b=45k a=500
---------------------------------+-------------+--------------+---------------
COLDSPEED solution:   0.0000206  |  0.0311071  |  0.0943433   |  4.5012770
Jean Fabre solution:  0.0000871  |  0.1722340  |  0.2635452   |  5.2981001
Jpp solution:         0.0000212  |  0.0474531  |  0.0464369   |  0.2450547
Ajax solution:        0.0000334  |  0.0303891  |  0.5262040   | 11.6994496
Daniel solution:      0.0000167  |  0.0162156  |  0.1301132   |  6.9071504
Kasramvd solution:    0.0000120  |  0.0084146  |  0.1704623   |  7.5648351
```

We can see Jpp solution is the fastest BUT we can't use it - it's the one solution from all others which can't work on combination of words (I already wrote him and hope he will improve his answer!). So looks like the [@cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49976619/4960953) 's solution is the fastest on the big data sets.

Comment: And why would you want to rewrite perfectly good code into a one-liner that's more difficult to read?

Comment: @Aran-Fey I'm not sure :) I thought it more `pythonic` and maybe a little faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with what you have, but if you want to clean things up a bit and performance isn't important, then compile a regex pattern and call `sub` inside a loop.

```
>>> import re
>>> p = re.compile(r'\b({})\b'.format('|'.join(a)))
>>> [p.sub('', text).strip() for text in b]
```

```
['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
 'consectetur adipiscing elit',
 'Nulla lectus ligula',
 'imperdiet at porttitor quis',
 'commodo eget tortor',
 'Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes'
]
```

**Details**
Your pattern will look something like this:

```
\b    # word-boundary - remove if you also want to replace substrings
(
test  # word 1
|     # regex OR pipe
smth  # word 2 ... you get the picture
)
\b    # end with another word boundary - again, remove for substr replacement
```

And this is the compiled regex pattern matcher:

```
>>> p
re.compile(r'\b(test|smth)\b', re.UNICODE)
```

Another consideration is whether your replacement strings themselves contain characters that could be interpreted by the regex engine differently - rather than being treated as literals - these are regex metacharacters, and you can escape them while building your pattern. That is done using `re.escape`.

```
p = re.compile(r'\b({})\b'.format(
    '|'.join([re.escape(word) for word in a]))
)
```

---

Of course, keep in mind that with larger data and more replacements, regex and string replacements both become tedious. Consider the use of something more suited to large operations, like [`flashtext`](http://flashtext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: You should probably change that `join(a)` to `join(re.escape(word) for word in a)` to be on the safe side in case the input contains any special regex characters

Comment: @Aran-Fey I thought about it... decided it would only serve to confuse. But you're right, will amend in the forthcoming iteration.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thank you again for so fast answer! As I understood, using `re` is slower than loop. Am I right?

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam The rule of thumb is that you may  not want regex unless you really want regex. However, the best thing to do is to test it out.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ can you please modify your script for using on combination of words? `a = ['test', 'smth commodo']` for example

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam I think it should work regardless, will you try it and let me know if it doesn't?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ It works! I added speed test for all the solutions. You can check it out in the question now! Thank you

Answer (score 3):

If the list is huge, building a ORed list of regular expressions (like `"\btest\b|\bsmth\b"`) can be quite long if the list of words to remove is big (`O(n)`). regex tests the first word, then the second ...

I suggest you use a *replacement function* using a `set` for word lookup. Return the word itself if not found, else return nothing to remove the word:

```
a = {'test', 'smth'}
b = ['test Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
     'consectetur adipiscing elit',
     'test Nulla lectus ligula',
     'imperdiet at porttitor quis',
     'smth commodo eget tortor',
     'Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes']

import re

result = [re.sub(r"\b(\w+)\b", lambda m : "" if m.group(1) in a else m.group(1),c) for c in b]

print(result)
```

> [' Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'consectetur adipiscing elit', ' Nulla lectus ligula', 'imperdiet at porttitor quis', ' commodo eget tortor', 'Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes']

Now if your list of "words" to replace contain strings composed of 2 words, this method doesn't work, because `\w` doesn't match spaces. A second pass could be done on the list of "words" made of 2 words:

```
a = {'lectus ligula', 'porttitor quis'}
```

and injecting the `result` in a similar filter but with explicit 2 word match:

```
result = [re.sub(r"\b(\w+ ?\w+)\b", lambda m : "" if m.group(1) in a else m.group(1),c) for c in result]
```

So 2 passes but if the list of words is huge, it's still faster than an exhaustive regex.

Comment: How to modify it to use for combination of words? I just tried `a = {'test', 'smth commodo'}` but it fails. As I suppose it's because of `\b ... \b` in regexp, isn't it?

Comment: aaah it's more difficult because you've got words in your list. The low complexity approach doesn't work as easily. Coldspeed answer should work, even if not super-efficient on a big list.

Comment: your question doesn't ask for that. You could add an edit it (adding some extra condition, without modifying the original). my approach would work with a second pass.

Comment: Yep it works! Thank you. Just want to test, what approach is faster!

Comment: I added speed test for all the solutions. You can check it out in the question now! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This is an alternative way using `set`, `str.join`, `str.split` and `str.strip`.

```
a_set = set(a)

b = [[' '.join([word if word not in a_set else ''
                for word in item.split()]).strip()]
     for item in b]

# [['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'],
#  ['consectetur adipiscing elit'],
#  ['Nulla lectus ligula'],
#  ['imperdiet at porttitor quis'],
#  ['commodo eget tortor'],
#  ['Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes']]
```

Comment: Interesting solution! But also I need to do one more action - convert list of lists to list of strings, isn't it?

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam, Yep by  no means am I implying this is the most efficient solution. You should test with your data if performance matters. If it doesn't, go with the most readable (probably not this one).

Comment: A slight variation of this answer would be `[" ".join(filter(lambda x: x not in a, k.split())) for k in b]`

Comment: @jpp It works perfectly. I add some complication for the question - can you improve your solution to work on combination of words please?

Comment: @jpp  I added speed test for all the solutions. You can check it out in the question now! Look at your result :)

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam, Unfortunately, my solution won't work on multiple words.. That's *why* this solution is fast. You'll have to go with another solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could use map and a regular expression.

```
import re
a = ['test', 'smth']
b = ['test Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
     'consectetur adipiscing elit',
     'test Nulla lectus ligula',
     'imperdiet at porttitor quis',
     'smth commodo eget tortor', 
     'Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes']

pattern=r'('+r'|'.join(a)+r')'
b=list(map(lambda x: re.sub(pattern,r'',x).strip(),b))
```

Comment: I added speed test for all the solutions. You can check it out in the question now! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As a pure functional approach (mostly for educational sake) is to utilize `partial` and `reduce` functions from `functools` module along with a `map` to apply the replacer function on your list of strings.

```
In [48]: f = partial(reduce, lambda x, y: x.replace(y + ' ', ''), a)

In [49]: list(map(f, b))
Out[49]: 
['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
 'consectetur adipiscing elit',
 'Nulla lectus ligula',
 'imperdiet at porttitor quis',
 'commodo eget tortor',
 'Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes']
```

Also if number of items in `a` is not very large there's nothing wrong with repeating the `replace()` multiple times. In this case, a very optimized and straightforward way is to use two `replace` as following:

```
In [54]: [line.replace(a[0] + ' ', '').replace(a[1] + ' ', '') for line in b]
Out[54]: 
['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
 'consectetur adipiscing elit',
 'Nulla lectus ligula',
 'imperdiet at porttitor quis',
 'commodo eget tortor',
 'Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes']
```

Comment: Using `reduce` is an interesting solution! Thank you!

Comment: I added speed test for all the solutions. You can check it out in the question now! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to join all the word combinations, and then replace `\s` with `|` for `re.sub`:

```
import re
b = ['test Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
 'consectetur adipiscing elit',
 'test Nulla lectus ligula',
 'imperdiet at porttitor quis',
 'smth commodo eget tortor', 
 'Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes']
a = ['test', 'smth commodo']
replaced_strings = [re.sub(re.sub('\s', '|', ' '.join(a)), '', i) for i in b]
```

Output:

```
[' Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'consectetur adipiscing elit', ' Nulla lectus ligula', 'imperdiet at porttitor quis', '  eget tortor', 'Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes']
```

To remove additional whitespace, apply an additional pass:

```
new_data = [re.sub('^\s+', '', i) for i in replaced_strings]
```

Output:

```
['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'consectetur adipiscing elit', 'Nulla lectus ligula', 'imperdiet at porttitor quis', 'eget tortor', 'Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes']
```

Comment: I added speed test for all the solutions. You can check it out in the question now! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for this:

```
[el.replace(a[0],'').replace(a[1],'') for el in b]
```

And if you want to remove spaces as well then use strip()

```
[el.replace(a[0],'').replace(a[1],'').strip() for el in b]
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you for solution! The problem is `a` list may be really long (10-20 strings).